# Async NUnit Test with await not listed in VS2013 Test Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nunit, async-await, .net-4.5

I ran into following problem. A NUnit async test using await to await a call returning GetCustomDataAsync is not listed in the Test Explorer. In the same, an async test await a call returning int GetDataAsync is shown in the Test Explorer. I break down the problem to this minimal code example:

```
public class CustomClient
{
    public async Task<int> GetDataAsync(int a, int b)
    {
        int result = a + b;
        // doing some work async
        await Task.Delay(250);
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<CustomClass> GetCustomDataAsync(int count)
    {
        CustomClass result = new CustomClass(count);
        // doing some work async
        await Task.Delay(250);
        return result;
    }
}

public class CustomClass
{
    private int _count;
    public CustomClass(int count)
    {
        _count = count;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set { _count = value; }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class CustomClientUnitTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task TestListedInTestExplorer()
    {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;
        int expectedResult = 6;

        CustomClient sut = new CustomClient();
        int result = await sut.GetDataAsync(a, b);

        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));
    }
    [Test]
    public async Task Test_NOT_ListedInTestExplorer()
    {
        int inCount = 5;
        int expectedOutCount = 6;

        CustomClient sut = new CustomClient();
        CustomClass customResult = await sut.GetCustomDataAsync(inCount);

        Assert.That(customResult.Count, Is.EqualTo(expectedOutCount));
    }
}
```

The CustomClient and CustomClass are in a ClassLibrary. The UnitTests are in separate ClassLibrary as well. I add a reference to the productive code in the UnitTest Project.

In the UnitTest Project I installed the following NuGet Packages:

- NUnitTestAdapter for VS2012 and VS2013, v1.2
- NUnit, v2.6.4

What I already tried so far, without success:

- Started VS2013 with/without admin rights.
- Various "Clean Solution" and "Build/Rebuild Solution".
- Changed the TEST -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture: x86/x64.
- Moved the second unit test to another unit test class.

What I’m missing here, or doing wrong? Why is the second async Unit Test not listed in the VS2013 Test Explorer?

**Edit**

I've done further testing, trying to isolate the problem:

- Using MSTest instead of NUnit, the async/await approach works with both Unit Tests, both Tests are listed in Test Explorer as expected.
- Using ReSharper 9 (used current demo version/trial) as Test Explorer/Runner and NUnit, both Tests are listed in the ReSharper Unit Test Explorer as expected.

So far, it looks like a problem with NUnit and the VS2013 Test Explorer, in detail, I think, a problem with the "integration" (NUnit Test Adapter for VS2013?).

Has someone already seen this problem? Or has any additional information?

Comment: I'm getting this issue, too. In the output window, it shows an error for every `async` test: `Exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException, Exception converting [Test name]`

Comment: @AJRichardson Not sure what the problem was back then. But (later...) I had also some strange issues because of special characters in the path. In my case it was a "#". I suggest the create or move (a new) project to a location/path without any special characters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.However I do not have any special charaters in my path (not even spaces).