# Tests not showing up in Test Explorer (Nunit)

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, nunit

**The problem**: My NUnit tests are not showing up in Test Explorer.

I am currently running Visual Studio Express 2013 on a 64-bit machine. At present, I have "NUnit TestAdapter including NUnit 2.6.4 framework" installed. The framework version is 2.6.4.14350, while the test adapter version is 2.0.0.0

Following these two threads ([NUnit Unit tests not showing in Test Explorer with Test Adapter is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298347/nunit-unit-tests-not-showing-in-test-explorer-with-test-adapter-is-installed) and [Visual Studio 2013 doesn't discover unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304425/visual-studio-2013-doesnt-discover-unit-tests)) on troubleshooting:

- At present, "Active Solution Platform" is set to 64-bit for build
  settings for my test project (Build > Configuration Manager).
- "Default Processor Architecture" is pointed to 64-bit under Test >
  Test Settings.
- A reference to both NUnit framework and TestAdapter have been
  specified in the test project.
- The test project cs file contains `[TestFixture]` and `[Test]` in the correct places
- I have tried cleaning / rebuilding the solution multiple times
- I have tried restarting Visual Studio multiple times
- I have tried running Visual Studio via "Run as administrator"
- I have tried running NUnit version 3 (framework and test adapter)

Below is my code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hello_World_Testing
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class HelloWorldTesting
    {
        [Test]
        public void subtract()
        {
            int value = 1;

            if (value == 1)
            {
                Assert.Pass();
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void addition()
        {
            int firstValue = 1;
            int secondValue = 2;

            Assert.AreEqual(3, firstValue + secondValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the NUnit adapter is having errors, they should show up in the output window of Visual Studio under Test in the dropdown. Is there anything there?

Comment: Hi Rob. Under Output, 0 found. No error messages.

Full message:
------ Discover test started ------
Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:02.6861536)

Comment: Can you run your tests using NUnit console? It may reveal more helpful errors.

Comment: Yes I can. I have trimmed the top, but the key section: <test-case name="Hello_World_Testing.HelloWorldTesting.addition" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.053" asserts="1" />
              <test-case name="Hello_World_Testing.HelloWorldTesting.subtract" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.032" asserts="0">

Comment: Are you using the extension or the nuget for the runner? Also, any reason your tests can't be AnyCPU?

Comment: I had similar issue last year with NUnit and VS2013. You can find my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185267/async-nunit-test-with-await-not-listed-in-vs2013-test-explorer). TL:DR: I had a special character in the path (it was a "#") that (as far as I can tell) caused my issue. Maybe worth to check for special character in your path and/or move the project to a different path.

Comment: Hi Rob - I installed the adapter and the framework via nuget (if that answers the question?). The only reason I have set it to 64-bit is so that the architecture is consistently set. I have tried AnyCPU as well, to no avail.

Comment: Hi 1ppCH - No special character in the path.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue and this worked for me.

Close Visual Studio
Go to:

```
C:/Users/YourUsername/AppData/Local/Temp
```

Rename the file called: `VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions`

-Open Visual Studio
and rebuild solution

Comment: Id appreciate you selecting this as an answer if it serves its purpose :)